# Vim: Key map bindings to open Firefox in background

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, macvim

" Open firefox - maps to **Option|Command|f**

```
map <M-D-f> :!/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P dev
```

The above works but blocks in Vim. I want to do:

```
map <M-D-f> :!/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P dev &
```

but Firefox does not open. Any suggestions on creating a key binding for opening firefox from within vim in the background? BTW, I'm actually using macvim. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
:!open -a Firefox
```

or

```
map <M-D-f> :!open -a Firefox^M
```

Don't forget to type `CTRL-v Enter` to get the `^M`.

I tested

```
map <C-f> :!/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P dev &^M
```

(since `<M-` and `<D-` don't seem to work for me inside Terminal.app vim), and it worked for me.